# R: apply the pclm function

Tags: r, apply

I have trouble to apply the  Penalized Composite Link Model (PCLM) function which only works with vectors. I use the pclm function to generate single years of age (syoa) population data from 5-year age group population data.

`pclm()` can be installed by following the instructions given by the author on https://github.com/mpascariu/ungroup.

Usage of the function:

```
pclm(x, y, nlast,control = list())

-x: vector of the cumulative sum points of the sequence in y.
-y: vector of values to be ungrouped.
-nlast: Length of the last interval.
-control: List with additional parameters.
```

Here's my training dataset:

```
data<-data.frame(
  GEOID= c(1,2),
  name= c("A","B"),
  "Under 5 years"= c(17,20),
  "5-9 years"= c(82,90),
  "10-14 years"= c(18, 22),
  "15-19 years"= c(90,88),
  "20-24 years"= c(98, 100), 
  check.names=FALSE)

#generating a data.frame storing the fitted values from the pclm for the first row: GEOID=1.

#using the values directly
syoa <- data.frame(fitted(pclm(x=c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), y=c(17,82,18,90,98), nlast=5, control = list(lambda = .1, deg = 3, kr = 1))))

#or referring to the vector by its rows and columns
syoa <- data.frame(fitted(pclm(x=c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), y=c(data[1,3:7]), nlast=5, control = list(lambda = .1, deg = 3, kr = 1))))
```

As my data have many observations, I'd like to apply the `pclm()` function across all the rows for columns 3-7: data[,3:7].

```
apply(data[3:7], 1, pclm(x=c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), y=c(data[,3:7]), nlast=5, control = list(lambda = .1, deg = 3, kr = 1)))
```

but it's not working and gives the following error message:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I don't know the issue's related to `apply()` or the `pclm ()`function. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than I thought.

```
pclm <- data.frame(apply(data[3:7], 1, function(x){
  pclm <- pclm(x=c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), y=c(x), nlast=5, control = list(lambda = NA, deg = 3, kr = 1)) 
  round(fitted(pclm))
}))
```